# how to check bluetooth status?

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {NativeModules, View } from 'react-native';

const BleComponent = () => {
       useEffect(() => {
             NativeModules.RNBluetoothManager.getBluetoothState().then(i => console.log(i));
       },  []);

       return <View />
};
```

When executing this code on Android, the method returns True/False, on IOS ruturns error that this method is undefined.

Added in info.plist:

- Privacy - Bluetooth Always Usage Description (string)
- Privacy - Bluetooth Peripheral Usage Description (string)

How i can fix it?